# Multilingual "Posted on: ... - By: ..." labels

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I would like to ask how to translate labels in drupal 7 like "**Posted on: ... - By: ...**".  I also have difficulties with translation for **prev-next** buttons text in calendar. I created a multilingual website based on Nexus 7.x-1.3 theme.

Comment: Please add which calendar are you using, if is Date popup, please add which version of Date module do you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 7.x-1.3 theme didn't considered internationalization for some of its  templates:
To enable it to translate **"Posted on: ... - By: ..."**, edit the node.tpl.php on line 90.

```
<ul class="meta clearfix">
  <li><strong>Posted on:</strong> <?php print $date; ?></li>
  <li><strong>By:</strong> <?php print $name; ?></li>
</ul>
```

you will need to use the [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function to change the lines to:

```
<ul class="meta clearfix">
  <li><strong><?php print t('Posted on:'); ?></strong> <?php print $date; ?></li>
  <li><strong><?php print t('By:'); ?></strong> <?php print $name; ?></li>  
</ul>
```

I'm not sure about which calendar you mean, in case that you are using the one bundled with Date module (Date popup), I believe those buttons can be translated using the Translate interface (admin/config/regional/translate/translate).

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I think I understood the power of t(), as I do not know php at all. The calendar also works now perfectly.